# Añadir elemento a un array múltiple atraves de una función Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

estoy haciendo un registro de usuarios usando un formulario y javascript, guardando los datos que quiero tomar en variables y atraves de la función validar añadiéndo ese array de elementos que he definido a un array de usuarios previamente creado(users)

El código es este:

```js
var user = document.getElementById("user");
var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
var users = [// user    password  rol
                  ["admin","admin", "1"],
              ];
var prueba;

enviar.addEventListener("click", validar, false);

function validar (e) {
  prueba = new Array(user.value+pass.value+"0");

  users.push(prueba);


    return users;
}
```

Comment: cambia el push por un merge

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, pero me sigue sin ir, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal, compruebo el valor de users desde la consola del navegador antes de hacer nada, y luego de añadir ia información desde el formulario vuelvo a comprobar para ver si se ha añadido el nuevo array, pero sigue sin añadirse nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que "users" es un array de arrays así que quizás esto debería ser así:

```
prueba = new Array(user.value, pass.value, "0");
```

o así

```
prueba = [user.value, pass.value, "0"];
```

Otra cosa a verificar es que el script que has escrito se ejecute una vez el DOM de la página haya cargado, o al menos que se ejecute una vez que los elementos que intentas buscar via id ya se hayan cargado

```
var user = document.getElementById("user");
var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
```

Comment: Hola Julio, he editado el código pero sigue sin funcionar, no se si quizás lo compruebo erróneamente, aquí esta https://jsfiddle.net/tuq79821/118/

Comment: Funciona https://jsfiddle.net/b1nfmj2d/, he añadido un alert para que lo puedas comprobar. Eso sí, he hecho algún cambio: He quitado las etiquetas <form> y también he definido el botón de enviar como 'button' en lugar de submit.

Comment: <form> y submit sería para enviar los datos al servidor (por ejemplo un script php) y entonces lo que estás haciendo guardando los usuarios en un array javascript no tendría ningún sentido. Creo que lo primero sería aclarar dónde deseas guardar los usuarios. ¿En una base de datos? ¿Temporalmente en la parte cliente utilizando javascript? ¿En memoria en la parte servidor (php, perl,...)?

Comment: Hola Julio, en primer lugar gracias, la practica consiste en hacer un registro y login solo usando html y javascript, estaba acostumbrado a practicar con php y no vi que el fallo estaba en el uso de la etiqueta form y submit .. , pero bueno, algo nuevo que se aprende, gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Me alegra. Si te sirvió puedes aceptar la respuesta :)